# Why does IE 11 not render Polymer elements with nested custom elements

Tags: internet-explorer, polymer, web-component

I have this html page:

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>      

        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="Greeter.html"/>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-greeter person="Ben"></app-greeter>
    </body>
</html>
```

and these custom elements:

Greeter.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>

<link rel="import" href="Person.html"/>

<dom-module  id="app-greeter">
    <style>
    </style>
    <template>
        Hello, <greet-person person="{{person}}"></greet-person><br>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is:"app-greeter",
        properties:{
            person:String
        }
    });
</script>
```

Person.html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>

<dom-module  id="greet-person">
    <style>
    </style>
    <template>
        <span>{{person}}</span><br>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is:"greet-person",
        properties:{
            person:String
        }
    });
</script>
```

In Chrome, this works perfectly. However in Firefox, Safari and IE 11 it displays a blank screen.

If I change the Greeter.html to not include the Person.html with the import and I just bind to the person attribute that is passed in it works fine. Also if I change Test.html to import just the Person.html and use just that element it renders fine.

It seems to be the combination of importing one element from within the other that seem to break IE 11, Firefox and Safari.

Of course this is a simplified example of a much bigger application where I am using imported custom elements in other imported custom elements.

I have tried various elements provided by Polymer Element library and they seem to work fine. I can not however see the error that I am making in my elements that seem to make my app not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Move `<script>` blocks inside `<dom-module>`. Also make sure webcomponents.js loaded on your page without errors.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in Chrome but not in other browsers it should be either an issue with the polyfill `webcomponents.js` (are you sure it is present and downloaded?), or with your cache (can you force download?).

Also, you'll need a HTTP server because HTML Imports won't work fine locally.

(I've no problem running your 3 files on IE 11 and Firefox.)